# Detecting the size of virtual keyboards

Tags: android, jquery, ios, virtual-keyboard, android-virtual-keyboard

Using javascript or JQuery, is there any way to detect the size of the android/iOS virtual keyboards?

I need this because when you full screen webpages, the screen (on android) doesn't automatically scroll to the input so the virtual keyboard actually ends up covering what I'm trying to type in.

Hopefully by finding the size, I can scroll the webpage accordingly.

Thanks in advance.